# Using Postman Generated Code in C# program

Tags: c#, api, screenshot, postman, imgur

I'm currently making an application that is going to upload images to imgur via postman/a c# application. I have authenticated my account with postman and i can upload images to imgur through the postman client. Now, im trying to do the actual uploading in the code for the rest of my program. Here is the code that is generated by postman

```
        var client = new RestClient("https://api.imgur.com/3/image");
        var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
        request.AddHeader("Postman-Token", "POSTMAN-TOKEN-GOES-HERE");
        request.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
        request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer BEARER-GOES-HERE");
        request.AddHeader("content-type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW");
        request.AddParameter("multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW", "------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"image\"\r\n\r\n\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW--", ParameterType.RequestBody);
        IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

So my question is, how do I implement this into the actual code? I want to have it execute upon a button click (that part isn't the problem). Is there something else i have to import? as obviously RestClient, RestRequest, method, and IRestResponse are not declared anywhere. Is there something that I have to import?

Any guidance with postman and the imgur api would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This is just example code created by Postman. If you want to use something that resembles that code, RestSharp looks like a good library.

Comment: @BrandonMiller that is RestSharp code, you can literally copy and paste it into a program with the appropriate references.

Comment: Yep, thats my question. How do i go about getting the appropriate libraries to use this code?

Comment: Typically you use Nuget to obtain references to things like RestSharp. I think you might want to invest some time in a couple of tutorials.

Comment: Ah, thank you for the correction. I didn't know for sure or not if it was. I always use HttpClient.

Comment: @Crowcoder Any suggestions for which tutorials to look into? i know im out of my depth, but it would be great to have some suggestions :)